# Lincap goes from rounded to squared when expanding layer in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I have a stroke with rounded caps. When I go to expand the stroke, the end turns back to squared while the beginning node is kept rounded. How do I preserve the rounded cap? https://screencast.com/t/WmCfdTR2z

[image: linecap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The last point has to have a bezier curve. [image: linecap]